# Is there anything like negative deceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity

I kinda understand acceleration, deceleration and negative acceleration but does anything like negative deceleration exist?

Comment: There's really no such thing as "deceleration." That's just an informal way of talking about an acceleration vector that points in approximately the opposite direction to the velocity vector. As for "positive" and "negative" those have their usual meaning for vectors: $-\vec{A}+\vec{A}=0$

Comment: *Negative* *de*celeration = $(-1) \times (-1) \times a = a$ = acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Deceleration is a term used in everyday language to say that an object is slowing down, the magnitude of its velocity is decreasing. The term exists because in everyday language, as opposed to physics, acceleration usually is not a signed quantity. "Negative deceleration" would mean an increase in velocity, which in everyday language is already described by "acceleration". And if you're thinking about signs and directions, you should be using the term "acceleration" because in physics "deceleration" isn't usually used.

Comment: I'd not go as far as saying we don't use the term "deceleration" in physics.  Heck, there are six Q&A's using the term in the "related" links table.  It's natural language even for physicists.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I've weakened the formulation with a "usually". But it should be very rare. During my studies and in a bit of research work afterwards I don't think I came across that word.